# Not able to find repeater inside FormView

Tags: c#, .net

I'm not able to locate the repeater controller called 'repScore' which is located inside the FormView controller.

This is my code:

```
<asp:FormView runat="server" id="fwHotelDetails" DataKeyNames="id" OnDataBound="fwHotelDetails_DataBound" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        // (..) some code here which outputs some data

        <asp:Repeater runat="server" id="repScore">
          <ItemTemplate>
            <span class="item"> <%# Eval("criteria") %>:</span>
          </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

And this is my code behind:

```
    protected void fwHotelDetails_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Repeater rep = (Repeater)fwHotelDetails.FindControl("repScore");

        rep.DataSource = this.dtCriteria;
        rep.DataBind();
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If the code above has been edited to reflect working code, you should also say that in your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot see that formView raises the DataBound event, didn't you forget declare event handler?

Comment: You are absolutely right. So I have added OnDataBound="fwHotelDetails_DataBound". Now I get the following error message: CS1061: 'ASP.templates_hoteldetails_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'fwHotelDetails_DataBound' and no extension method 'fwHotelDetails_DataBound' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.templates_hoteldetails_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Thanks for your heads up. I got that errormessage because the function was set to private. Once I used Protected instead, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment yet... so here it goes:

basically it means it has no access to method you declared...

changing the "private" to "protected" (or "internal", or "public", depends on what you need) should help.